# take json input from command line and parse the data in java

Tags: java, json, maven, parsing, jackson

I want to take a (command + JsonData) pattern from command line as input and I don't know how to do it in java. I would be very grateful if anyone can help.
imagine that I have some command + JsonData like this:

```
addOffering  {"code":"81013602","name":"course name","Instructor":"the teacher name",
             "units":3,"classTime": {"days": ["saturday","Monday"], "time":"16-17:30"},
             "examTime": {"start": "2021-9-01T08:00:00","end": "2021-9-01T08:00:00"},"capacity":60,
             "prerequisites": ["Advanced Programming","Operating Systems"]}
```

in the program I have several commands (like addOffering) so I should take other commands as input.
for taking inputs I am using scanner (but I don't know whether it's a good idea) because i'm new to java.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String command = scanner.next();
        if(command.equals("exit")) {
                    break;
        }
}
```

in a while loop I wish to take my inputs and parse command from JsonData to call several functions for different commands and also to initialize my classes fields by the Json data using object mapper(jackson). any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to pass command and JSON payload when you run your application, for example: `java -jar JarExample.jar addOffering JSON_PAYLOAD`? Or you want to run it without arguments and application will read them later from command line? In both cases you should separate command from JSON payload. So, first ask user for a command and after that ask for a `JSON payload`. It will allow you to validate provided data separately and show in console error message.

Comment: @MichałZiober thank you for responsing, I got a problem here with intellij idea and thats when I want to paste the Json data or anything else in the intellij console (terminal) it says this view is read only, what does it mean?! how can I fix it? I searched a lot but I didn't find any thing useful, If you could help me I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually doing but you can always generate  `jar` file and run it in system terminal like I shown in previous comment: `java -jar your-jar-name.jar` Take a look on this video tutorial [User Input with Scanner - Getting Started with Java 4 (IntelliJ IDEA)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp1zTlWdVdI) how to work with app console.